# How to get the fully url from a dynamic website

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, dom, server-side

Consider a dynamic website running an application, where you can see the URL from your browser as:

`www.example.com/game`

Now the /game is probably a folder? And how can i see the actual path to the application?
Can't I see the server side scripting language, such as:

`www.example.com/game/robobo.php`   or

`www.example.com/game/robobo.aspx`  or something similar?

Now, I know you can guess some of these (typically with the "index" name), however there may be many subfolders.

Comment: The app probably uses URL routing or URL re-writing. The actual files may not be publicly visible at all. Generally you cannot see the source scripts on a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the /game is probably a folder?

It is part of the URL. That's all you can know about it.

> And how can i see the actual path to the application?

You cannot.

How the URL maps on to the server's file system (or even if it maps on the file system at all) is not information that the webserver will expose.

> Can't I see the server side scripting language

Not really.

There might be fingerprints in the HTTP response headers that could clue you in, or HTML returned in the response body might include fingerprints from a particular CMS which would imply a programming language, but there is nothing certain.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When you think about it, dealing with a blind url like .../game, you have no idea whatsoever what the underlying platform is - might be Asp.Net, might be classic Asp, might be PHP - might even be Python or Ruby... Since you don't know what system sits on the server, you are not going to be able to know what to do to get the full path...

Answer (score 0):

Most CMS systems allow the website owner to change the true URL to something more user and search engine friendly (sometimes called Permalinks or SEO URLs). /games, does not mean that there is such a folder, it could be a category name or a tag. The only place where you can see full paths is for media assets such as images and videos. (right click, view image source or open image in a new tab).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are the admin of the website, it is nearly impossible to find the real path. 
I am saying nearly impossible since you already pointed out on guessing.
The server side is obviously hidden from visitors.

You can guess what is the technology used on a website by testing it on other websites such as builtwith.com. 
For example if it shows php, then there is a great probability that all files end with .php.