# How can I find a dynamic url on a webpage?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Guys I want to be able to know how you can find a dynamic url on a website. Primarily, I am looking for the search term at the end of a website. For example how would I find the link https://www.abbeywhisky.com/pages/search-results-page?q= from entering the front page of https://www.abbeywhisky.com

I am unsure if there is a way to do this by just using the landing page of a site. I would have tried to scrape the first page of the site but using the filter of "?=" does not shown any results.

Comment: what if you use the filter `?q=` instead? looks like you just forgot the `q`

Comment: This has been answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623946/how-to-get-the-fully-url-from-a-dynamic-website)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the fully url from a dynamic website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623946/how-to-get-the-fully-url-from-a-dynamic-website)